# How to control page's cacheability after login action

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, cache-control, akamai

I have this code:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
```

I'm trying to cache the entire page on client's browser and any other proxy in between client browser and my servers.

It's all working well until one user logins. After this action all users have in the header the user name and a logout button.

How can I solve this issue?

I think I have 2 options:

1. Cache the entire page without user info on the header. Then, make a async request to get user's information
2. Write a cookie every time the user logins and control CDN cache with this cookie (just cache if there is no cookie https://docs.fastly.com/guides/caching/how-do-i-use-a-cookie-as-a-cache-key)

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of ESI feature in Akamai.